# Image of item changes when scroll up and down listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have used custom Base Adapter for listview. Each row contains progressbar, imagebutton and 2 textview. I have made an audio player for each row with play button (which changes its image to pause on clicking) and progressbar (which starts showing progress as the button clicks). The problem arise when i scroll list:

1) When i scroll down and get back, the image of imagebutton returns to play and progressbar clears its progress although song is still playing.

2) Other items of listview starts showing pause images on their imagebutton and progressbar shows the progress of the song being played(I think after every 6th row the 7th one does that).
Please help me. Here is my custom adapter:

```
public class AudioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
Uri[] URIs;
LayoutInflater layout;
ImageButton previousButton = null;
ProgressBar previousProgressBar = null;
static private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

public AudioAdapter(Context context, int resource, Uri[] URIs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context = context;
    this.URIs = URIs;
}

class AudioViewHolder {
    ImageButton play;
    TextView date, duration;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public AudioViewHolder(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated constructor
        // stub
        play = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_rowAudioplay);
        date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_rowAudioDate);
        duration = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_rowAudioDuration);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v
                .findViewById(R.id.progressBar_rowAudioplay);

    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return URIs.length;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    final AudioViewHolder holder;
    if (row == null) {

        layout = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layout.inflate(R.layout.row_hometab_audio, parent, false);
        row.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder = new AudioViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (AudioViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    holder.duration.setText(AudioPlayer.getAudioMinutes(context,
            URIs[position])
            + ":"
            + AudioPlayer.getAudioSeconds(context, URIs[position]));
    DebugMessage.logMessage("Inside AudioAdapter getView() . isrowNULL = "
            + (row == null));
    holder.progressBar.setTag(position);
    holder.play.setTag(position);
    holder.play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int row_position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            if (holder.play == previousButton && AudioPlayer.isPlaying)
                AudioPlayer.pauseAudio(holder);
            else {
                if (holder.play == previousButton
                        && AudioPlayer.isPlaying == false) {
                    AudioPlayer.resumeAudio(holder);
                    AudioPlayer.ProgressBarUpdate(holder, myHandler);
                } else if (AudioPlayer.isPlaying) {
                    AudioPlayer.StopAudio(previousButton,
                            previousProgressBar);
                    AudioPlayer.PlayAudio(context, URIs[row_position],
                            holder);
                    AudioPlayer.ProgressBarUpdate(holder, myHandler);
                    holder.play
                            .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                    previousButton = holder.play;
                    previousProgressBar = holder.progressBar;
                    AudioPlayer.isPlaying = true;
                } else {
                    AudioPlayer.PlayAudio(context, URIs[row_position],
                            holder);
                    AudioPlayer.ProgressBarUpdate(holder, myHandler);
                    holder.play
                            .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                    previousButton = holder.play;
                    previousProgressBar = holder.progressBar;
                    AudioPlayer.isPlaying = true;
                }
            }
            AudioPlayer.onAudioFinished(holder);
        }
    });

    row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return row;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my player:

```
public class AudioPlayer {
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
static String time;
public static boolean isPlaying = false;
static int currProgress;

public static void ProgressBarUpdate(
        final AudioAdapter.AudioViewHolder holder, final Handler myHandler) {
    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            currProgress = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            holder.progressBar.setProgress(currProgress);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }, 100);
}

public static void PlayAudio(Context context, Uri filePath,
        AudioAdapter.AudioViewHolder holder) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, filePath);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.progressBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    holder.play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
    mediaPlayer.start();

}

public static void pauseAudio(AudioAdapter.AudioViewHolder holder) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
}

public static void StopAudio(ImageButton play,ProgressBar progressBar) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
}

public static void resumeAudio(AudioAdapter.AudioViewHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mediaPlayer.start();
    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.progressBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    holder.play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
}

public static void onAudioFinished(final AudioAdapter.AudioViewHolder holder) {
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DebugMessage.logMessage("Audio Completed");
            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }
    });
}

public static String getAudioMinutes(Context context, Uri filePath) {
    int duration = MediaPlayer.create(context, filePath).getDuration();
    int min = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) duration);
    if (min < 10)
        return String.valueOf("0" + min);
    else
        return String.valueOf(min);
}

public static String getAudioSeconds(Context context, Uri filePath) {
    int duration = MediaPlayer.create(context, filePath).getDuration();
    long sec = (long) (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) duration) - TimeUnit.MINUTES
            .toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) duration)));
    if (sec < 10)
        return String.valueOf("0" + sec);
    else
        return String.valueOf(sec);
}
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The logic within the click event, where it actually changes the Views assign images and visibility...that needs to happen for every `getView()` call.

So lets say you are playing `Song X`.  If that view scrolls off the screen, and then comes back on the screen...it'll fire off `getView()`.  That `getView()` call needs to be able to restore the View to the state of it playing a song.

So Ideally, for every `getView()` you need a way to say, "Hey, I have this URI.  Please tell me if it's playing and how many seconds along is it."  Then update your views accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these methods to your adapter class :

```
@Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
  }
```